# Using an MVC SelectList in webforms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, selectlist

I would like to have grouped items within an asp.net dropdownlist and I thought of using the SelectList functionality from MVC to my webforms project. Here's what I have tried and the result. Can you help please with the binding?

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlGroupBySelGeo" AutoPostBack="True"
       DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value"
       SelectMethod="GetMapItems" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGroupBySelGeo_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

public SelectList GetMapItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var group1 = new SelectListGroup() { Name = "Select" };
    var group2 = new SelectListGroup() { Name = "Group" };

    items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "display selected",                                 Value = "select",           Group = group1 });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = GetLocalResourceObject("Region").ToString(),        Value = "Regional",         Group = group2 });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = GetLocalResourceObject("Municipality").ToString(),  Value = "Municipio",        Group = group2 }); 
    items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = GetLocalResourceObject("Locality").ToString(),      Value = "Localidade",       Group = group2 });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = GetLocalResourceObject("Neighborhood").ToString(),  Value = "Bairro",           Group = group2 });            

    return new SelectList(items);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `Value` and `Text` parameters in the `SelectList` before you return it?

```
return new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
```